# Why doesn't this code give the right results for numeric comparisons?

Tags: python

I am currently doing Udemy course for Python by Jose Portilla. I am still a complete beginner. The excercise is the following:

"Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere."

```
has_33([1, 3, 3]) → True
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) → False
has_33([3, 1, 3]) → False
```

My code is the following. For my logic it should give me the above results, but it gives False, False, True, which is completely off:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for n in nums:
        a = nums.index(n)
        x = nums[a + 1]
        y = nums[a - 1]
        if n == 3 and (x == n or y == n):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how to solve the problem or why your code doesn't work?

Comment: I am asking why it does not work? I simply don't get it. All of the steps are stroed in variables so they should not give any None Types. Clueless.

Comment: `a = nums.index(n)` noo. Don't do that. That isn't even correct, that always gives you the *first index* where `n` occurs.

Comment: You should use `for i, n in enumerate(nums):` to get the corresponding index for `n`

Comment: @StingerWolf well, the first issue is that it always returns on the first iteration.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, I think I understand now. It finds the 1 at first which is not 3 so it returns false already at the beginning. Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Thank you guys, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @Carcigenicate no it is not going out of bounds. When the index gets negative it just accesses the list from reverse. Hence, no error is thrown.

Comment: @jeanggi90 Oh right, I forget Python has the wrapping behavior. My bad. Potentially unintended behavior here though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to explain the working of your function for `has_33([1, 3, 3])`. This way it gets obvious why your function is not doing what you expect it to do.

```
def has_33(nums):
    # Call function and nums = [1, 3, 3]

    for n in nums:
        # Iterate over nums. n = 1

        a = nums.index(n)
        # Get the index of the list a where element = 1; a = 0

        x = nums[a + 1]
        # 0 + 1 = 1 -> x = nums[1] = 3

        y = nums[a - 1]
        # 0 - 1 = -1 -> y = nums[-1] = 3 (index -1 points to the last element of the list)

        if n == 3 and (x == n or y == n):
            # False, since n != 3 (even though x = 3 and y = 3)

            return True
        else:
            return False
            # When returning, the functin stopts executing, hence n never reaches another element.
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the main reason why this doesn't work is that you return false on the first iteration. Concerning the implementation, you can simplify things a bit to understand a bit more clearly what's going on:

```py
def has_33(nums):
    for a in range(len(nums)-1):
        x = nums[a]
        y = nums[a + 1]
        if x == 3 and y == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

In your original solution, you were iterating over items by group of 3, adding `print(y, n, x)` right before your test would have output the following (for a call to `has_33([1, 2, 3, 3, 4])`):

```py
item at:   i-1    i    i+1
           ---------------
i = 0       4     1     2
i = 1       1     2     3
i = 2       2     3     3
```

In the first line, `4 1 2`, the `4` is the item at position `0-1 = -1`, in python, negative indexes correspond to positions **relative to the end of the list**. For example, `nums[-1]` is the last item from `nums` and `nums[-2]` is the one before the last, etc.

In this second code we just iterate through `nums`'s indexes to get every `x` item together with the following item `y`, printing `print(x, y)` would give:

```py
item at:    i    i+1
           ---------
i = 0       1     2
i = 1       2     3
i = 2       3     3
```

Remark that, in the end we just used the indexes to get items, when the index is not used for anything else, you can often use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) function instead:

```py
def has_33(nums):
    for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
        if x == 3 and y == x:
            return True
    return False

has_33([1, 2, 3, 3, 1])
```

This outputs `True`, and for the record:

```py
>>> nums
[1, 2, 3, 3, 1]
>>> nums[1:]
[2, 3, 3, 1]
>>> list(zip(nums, nums[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1)]
```

The `zip` function will pair item at index `i` from the first list with item  at index `i` from the second list. Here we just removed the first item from `nums` to form our second list, using this strategy we managed to pair item `i` with item `i+1`.

As mentioned in the comments, you can even use the function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) that does exactly what our loop does

```py
def has_33(nums):
    return any(p == (3, 3) for p in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

Comment: you can further shorten your solution to `def has_33(nums): return any(x == y == 3 for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]))`

Comment: You surely can, introducing `zip` to the OP was the main goal here, as I think it really is something hard to understand for python beginners. Both `any` or `all` are pretty straightforward (I think). But that's always worth mentioning, if you think I should add it I will.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error in your code at line 3. You can't use:

```
a = nums.index(n)
```

To get the index but you need to use this way:

```
for a, n in enumerate(nums):
```

Finally there is your corrected code:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for a, n in enumerate(nums):
        x = nums[a + 1]
        y = nums[a - 1]
        if n == 3 and (x == n or y == n):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**WHY?** nums.index(n) return the first position of n not the current position.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can try this.

```
def has_33(numbers):
    str_numbers = ''.join(map(str, numbers))
    return '33' in str_numbers
```

The function accepts as an argument a `list`, the variable `str_numbers` contains the list converted to a string by the `map` function and `join` method.

For example, if my list is

```
my_numbers = [1,3,1,3]
```

The variable stores it as

```
'1313'
```

Last but not least, return an evaluation of an expression to see if `'33'` is in the new created variable, which returns `True` or `False`.

### Run this

```
my_numbers = [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3]


def has_33(numbers):
    str_numbers = ''.join(map(str, numbers))
    return '33' in str_numbers


result = has_33(my_numbers)
print(result)
```